# dimensional modelling outrigger dimension usage in ssas

Tags: ssas, dimensional-modeling

I have a DimPerson table and a DimPersonDecileOutrigger Table which stores decile data. The way the outrigger is structured is that a customer is given a decile for current year and previous year (if they have bought in the period)- which means a customer might have TY and NOT LY and vice versa. Some customers are both.

In ssis when I picked the columns in dimension structure- I initially only picked columns from DimPerson and not the outrigger. That way in the browser it showed all the id's starting from 1. But when I dragged some columns from outrigger- then in the browser it doesnt show all personID's. I want to see all customers regardless of them having a decile or not.

Pic attached to show what it looks like in dimension structure tab. Also the relationship is between OutriggerID as primary and OutriggerID in person as foreign.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to solve the problem, you can create a `View` in your underlying relational database that uses LEFT OUTER JOIN to link the two tables, so that the view will return all rows from DimPerson, even if they don't have a Decile.

Then use the view as the source for your dimension instead of the tables.